# Select all nth occurrence of an element in css

Tags: html, css

I need to provide a separate style for every 5th row on my `html`. For example: the 5th, 10th, 15th, 25th, ... rows has a gray background compared to other rows that are not multiples of 5. My problem is that I don't know what is the proper `css` selector for that.

These are the things I already did to achieve this effect, *but trying to avoid if possible*:

1. Adding a `class` attribute to every fifth occurrence:

   ```
       <style>
           tbody tr.5th-row {
               .....
           }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <thead>
           <tr>...</tr>
           <tr>...</tr>
           <tr>...</tr>
           <tr>...</tr>

           <tr class="5th-row">...</tr>

           <tr>...</tr>
           <tr>...</tr>
           <tr>...</tr>
           <tr>...</tr>

           <tr class="5th-row">...</tr>
       </thead>
   ```
2. Using JavaScript to iterate all rows and change the style for every fifth row:

   ```
   var trs = $("tbody tr")

   for(var trx = 0; trx < trs.length; trx++) {
       if(trx + 1 % 5 == 0) {
           var tr = $(trs[trx])
           tr.css({
               .....
           })
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: `:nth-child` is your friend

Comment: By the way, note that CSS identifiers can't begin with a digit, so `.5th-row` wouldn't work, but could be escaped as `.\35 th-row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `nth-child` selector for this

```
tr:nth-child(5n) {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: What's with the `n` in `:nth-child(5n)`?

Comment: The formula is (an + b) where `a` represents a cycle size and `n` is a counter starting at `0` and b is an offset value.